# py2exe cmd failure

Tags: python

i wrote a python script and installed py2exe 0.6.9 (win32) to a 32bit-Windows7 machine with Python 2.7. I could successfully run "python setup.py py2exe" via cmd.
Now I installed py2exe 0.6.9 (win64) to a 2nd PC (Win7, 64bit, Python2.7) and tried the same to exactly the same script:
But "python setup.py py2exe" returned this message (hope I translated it correctly into english):
"The command 'python' is either written wrong or couldn't be found."
Why does this happen? How can I solve this?

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste the actual error message. Even if it's not in English, there are probably other users here who speak your language, and even those who don't can copy and paste it to find out exactly which error you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `py2exe`, and everything to do with the machine's setup.

You don't have `python` on your path. You can test this by just running `python` by itself to open the interactive interpreter. If `cmd` can't find `python`, it can't run it.

Here are some ways around this:

- Explicitly use the full path to Python—e.g., if it's `C:\Python27\bin\Python.exe`, type that instead of just `python`.
- Temporarily edit your PATH environment variable in the `cmd` window. With the above example, this would be `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27\bin`. You will have to do this again every time you reboot, open a new `cmd` window, etc.
- Permanently edit your PATH environment variable. This is done in the Advanced System Settings controls, which I believe are still accessible through the Properties on the context menu for My Computer in Windows 7.
- Uninstall and reinstall Python, and this time allow it to put itself on your path.
- Ask for further help at superuser or some other site that's focused on system configuration problems rather than programming problems.